# How do I remove white background from ion-items in ionic 4?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am having massive problems styling my ionic 4 mobile app layouts. It took a while for me just to find out how to set a background image for the app, but now I am getting a white rectangle wherever I put an ion-item tag. ive tried setting the ion-item {background: transparent important!} (in page scss) but its not working. I am a complete beginner to ionic!

register.page.scss

```
:host { ion-content {
--background:none;
background: url('../../assets/imgs/hoghi/bg.jpg')  no-repeat 100% 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;

ion-item {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  opacity:1;
}//end of item}//end of content}//end of :host
```

register.page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input></ion-input> 
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

[image: This is the output im getting.. the input works fine.]

Comment: yes i know the '}' are commented at the end of my register.page.scss I was having problems with formating them to fit in the code block hehe.. any help is apprecciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try using the Shadow DOM variables to achieve that.

Ionic components' styles are customizable using these variables.

> Get more info for ion-item [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties)

Following your code that would be:

```css
ion-item {
  --background: none;
  opacity:1;
}
```

> [More information on Shadow DOM](https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components/)

You can always find these variables at the end of the page in each component's documentation

Comment: This did the trick wonderfully.. I will definitly look into the page you linked since I read that ionic 4 has different styling rules then previous ionic versions. Very helpful. Thank you sir.